# Characterization in UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am self-studying some algebra from the AMS notes, but I am stuck in the proof characterizing UFD as those integral domains that satisfy the equivalence between primes and irreducibles, and ACCP. So here's the problem. It is said that, given two irreducible elements $a$ and $b$ such that $a|b$, it must be that they are associates (there must be a unit $u$ such that $au=bu$). I can't see how to see this: since $a|b$ and both are irreducible, the element $v$ such that $av=b$ must be a unit, but I don't understand how to use this fact.

Comment: That $av = b$ for some unit $v$ is typically the definition of $a$ is associate to $b$. You have the definition wrong, which is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$au=bu$ implies that $(a-b)u=0$ since a unique factorization domain is an integral domain, $a=b$, so look carefully to your definition of associate elements.

Remark that if $b=va$ with $v$ a unit, $a=v^{-1}b$ so $b$ divides $a$ also which is also a definition of associate elements ($a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $a$).

Comment: Yeah I had the same doubt, but the definition of association that the notes give is (verbatim) "two elements $a$ and $b$ are said to be associates provided $au=bu$ for some unit $u$". I am somewhat a newbie so if there is an error in these notes I can't spot it

Comment: @Enrico That's surely a typo.  Better to delete questions about typos  since they are so isolated to be rarely useful to others.

Comment: I tried but stackexchange doesn't let me. Anyway thanks